# Java, multiple inheritance. How should I do this?

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am creating a employee wage system. I have an abstract `Employee` class. `WageEmployee` and `Manager` extend `Employee`. Then Programmer and `SalesPerson` extend `WageEmployee`.

My problem is that I want to create a `SalesManager`. The `SalesManger` has thier pay computed by adding commission and a salary. So they have type `SalesPerson` and `Manager`.

What should I make an interface and what should `SalesPerson` extend?

It is only natural to extend `SalesManager` from manager, then make `SalesPerson` an interface. But I cannot because it inherits from `WageEmployee`...

How do I get this to work. properly?

```
abstract class Employee 
{
  String name;

  Employee() {}
  Employee (String nm) { name = nm; }
  abstract double computePay();
  void display () {}
  void setHours(double hrs) {}
  void setSales(double sales) {}
  void setSalary(double salary) { System.out.println("NO!"); }
```

}

Comment: Is there functionality that is being inherited, or is it just methods?

Comment: I'd, personally, start with all interfaces, this will give you the greatest deal of flexibility.  Then you need to figure out from there which abstract implementations are going to produce the least amount of re-work.  The only other solution you have is to use a proxy style solution.  That is, the functionality of one interface is actually implemented by a proxy object which the parent object maintains a reference to and calls on it's behalf.

Comment: Interfaces and object composition are your friends in this case.

Comment: You should probably start looking into another way of modeling your employees.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call me crazy, but you may not need to subclass to deal with the different pay methods here. Instead, consider using the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to figure out wages/sales commissions. That way, you have a class `Employee` and its subclass `SalesEmployee`; each of these would have as a property a `PayStrategy` object, which can have concrete subclasses `WagePayStrategy` and `CommissionPayStrategy`. If you define the right methods on `PayStrategy` (could be an interface or abstract class), you can have your `Employee` instances ask the strategy objects what pay the employee gets for certain inputs (hours worked, sales made, etc.).

Consider the following trivial example:

```
interface PayStrategy {
    public float getPay(float hoursWorked, float salesMade);
}

class WageStrategy implements PayStrategy {
    public float getPay(float hoursWorked, float salesMade) {
        return hoursWorked * 8.5;
    }
}

class CommissionStrategy implements PayStrategy {
    public float getPay(float hoursWorked, float salesMade) {
        return salesMade * 0.5 + hoursWorked * 5.0;
    }
}

abstract class Employee {
    public PayStrategy payStrategy; // assign as needed

    public float getPay(float hoursWorked, float salesMade) {
        return this.payStrategy.getPay(hoursWorked, salesMade);
    }
}
```

Note how you can change the pay strategy for any given employee without needing a different class, giving you more flexibility and encapsulation around that algorithm.

Comment: It's also possible to have PayStrategy.getPay take a single generic float value. Then the SalesManager could have a combined strategy implementation like so:
public float getPay(float ignored) { return wageStrategy.getPay(getHoursWorked()) + commissionStrategy.getPay(getSalesMade()); }
where the SalesManager class has a salesMade and an hoursWorked field.

Comment: @AngerClown: True, but then what's the point of the parameter? You might as well just place `getHoursWorked()` and `getSalesMade()` (even if abstractly) on Employee, fix up default return values (e.g. 0) where they don't matter, and drop `float ignored` altogether. If you're deliberately calling parameters `ignored`, something's amiss IMO.

Answer (score 1):

`Employee` has methods `getFixedSalary()` and `getComissionSalary()`.

You can create abstract subclasses `SalariedEmployee` (`getComissionSalary` always returns 0) and make `Programmer` and `SalesPerson` expand it. `SalesManager` implements directly `Employee`.

Or all the classes directly inherit from `Employee`, to grant maximum flexibility should salary scales change some day (I would go this way). Write helper methods to avoid duplicating code but given you still options to change the modus operandi if needed later.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend Classes, you usually want to keep some sort of functionality and you add onto it by extending it. With an Interface, it gives you list of methods that an object will have.

It looks like you have `Employee`s and `Manager`s, and you have to decide where the functionality is going to be extended from. Without looking at your code or object model, it looks like everyone's an `Employee` and some of them are `Manager`. So it looks like you need to decide what extra a Manager does that makes it separate from an Employee. Then everything will extend `Employee`, and extend subclasses of `Employee` (`WageEmployee`, `SalaryEmployee`, etc), then the ones that are Managers, they implement a `Manager` interface. So you can have a `SalesPerson` extending a `WageEmployee` and then a `SalesManager` extending `SalesPerson` that implements `Manager`.